# Read HDFS file splits

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, distributed-computing

With HDFS's Java API, it's straightforward to read a file sequentially reading each block at a time. Here's a [simple example](https://sites.google.com/site/hadoopandhive/home/hadoop-how-to-read-a-file-from-hdfs).

I want to be able to read the file one *block* at a time using something like HDFS's [FileSplits](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileSplit.html). The end goal is to read a file in parallel with multiple machines, each machine reading a zone of blocks. Given a HDFS Path, how can I get the FileSplits or blocks?

Map-Reduce and other processors are not involved. This is strictly a file system level operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you would get the blocks locations of a File in HDFS

```
  Path dataset = new Path(fs.getHomeDirectory(), <path-to-file>);
  FileStatus datasetFile = fs.getFileStatus(dataset);

  BlockLocation myBlocks [] = fs.getFileBlockLocations(datasetFile,0,datasetFile.getLen());
  for(BlockLocation b : myBlocks){
    System.out.println("Length "+b.getLength());
    for(String host : b.getHosts()){
      System.out.println("host "+host);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is internal HDFS code that's used to calculate file checksums,  it does exactly what you need.

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/2.4.0/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/DFSClient.java#1863